# It is necessary to replace all characters of the string with the adjacent character (shift all characters to the right by 1)

Tags: kotlin

It is necessary to replace each character in the string cyclically with the character adjacent to the right, and then collect it into a string again.

Instead of shifting characters to the right, it turns out to increase alphabetically

```
fun main {
    val message = "abcd1234"
    val messageSecond = message.map {char -> char + 1}.joinToString ("")
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! What is your question? You seem to have posted an assignment and some code. Is there something wrong with the code? Please see [ask] and consider taking the [tour]

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong as it increases the ASCII code of each character and as you noted yourself it increases "alphabetically" (not exactly, just in [ASCII order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6NAv.jpg))

I can't write the code for you as it seems to be an assignment, but I can give you a hint.

###### You can actually solve this just by "moving" only one character.

Best of luck!

Comment: That's right, this is just an example, I want to understand how everything works, but I do not have enough tools to complete the task, and I have not found the answers yet, because I am at the beginning of the journey.

and thank you)